# How to communicate with a device?

Tags: java, hardware

I am a web programmer and I am just wondering how software and hardware can communicate. I have basic knowledge in Java but I am not an expert.

Let's make it simple. I have a device which is just a simple lamp that can get switched on and off and it is connected via USB. My software has only one function - pressing enter.

By pressing enter I want the software to communicate with the USB port and tell it to activate the device. How would that be possible? Where do I have to start and what do I need to learn?

I understand that my question and my example sound silly but I am just trying to understand how it works.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You would need to read the documentation of your lamp to see how to communicate with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you using arduino or other prototyping board you might use `rxtx` serial library.

Answer (score 0):

If I answer simply, then I should tell, you need to have `microcontroller` to do this by your own.

A `microcontroller` is a small computer on a single integrated circuit.  A `microcontroller` contains one or more CPUs (processor cores) along with memory and programmable input/output peripherals. So, there are input, output pins for different operations you want to do with your physical hardware and also a memory to store the commands or program. That means a microcontroller is a third party which keeps communication active between the hardware and software in this case.

In the market, you can find many microcontroller integrated boards for building digital devices and interactive objects that can sense and control objects in the physical world.

To make your work easy as a beginner, I suggest you to buy an `arduino` board from the market. If you google it and search for arduino tutorials in youtube, you will find how they work. Hope these help you.